# SUMO simulator installation on macOS Sierra (2017)

Tags: sumo

do you have any recent-installation-guide for installing SUMO on macOS Sierra (I have macBook 13'') that worked for you ?? (2017). I found several guides on the internet but I'am not sure what is the best solution. Would it be better to make a virtual machine with Ubuntu and install/run it on it? Please give me some hints and maybe experiences with installing SUMO on mac. Thanx :)

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way is currently homebrew, see http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Installing/MacOS_Build_w_Homebrew.
You can also try

```
brew install homebrew/science/sumo
```

which may install a slightly outdated sumo.

Comment: Ycos-MacBook-Pro:/ Yzak$ sudo autoreconf -i
autoreconf: 'configure.ac' or 'configure.in' is required

Comment: this problem occurs when i try autoreconf -i

Comment: You need to download the sources first, I updated the wiki.

Comment: Thank God for you :-) 
then I did this.

svn co https://svn.code.sf.net/p/sumo/code/trunk/sumo
cd sumo
make -f Makefile.cvs
SUMO_HOME="/home/<user>/sumo-<version>"; export SUMO_HOME

and when Iam in Yzak/sumo directory I cannot do 
cd sumo-svn
can you help me? Iam really new to mac and bash.

Comment: no you are already in the right directory, you can just go on with configure (the Makefile.cvs already did the autoconf thing),

Comment: God bless you Michael, I made next step ./configure CXX=clang++ CXXFLAGS="-stdlib=libc++ -std=gnu++11" --with-xerces=/usr/local --with-proj-gdal=/usr/local                      and then            make -j`sysctl -n hw.ncpu`  and it was installing something for a while until this error occured fatal error/usr/local/Cellar/fox/1.6.55/include/fox-1.6/xincs.h: :188:10: fatal error: 
      'X11/X.h' file not

Comment: I think the fox thing could not find a path to X11... what should I do next?

Comment: did you install the xquartz successfully?

Comment: I hope so..

i tried it from beginning and when I do autoreconf -i this error is shown

glibtoolize: Consider adding 'AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS([m4])' to configure.ac,
glibtoolize: and rerunning glibtoolize and aclocal.
glibtoolize: Consider adding '-I m4' to ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS in Makefile.am.
glibtoolize: 'AC_PROG_RANLIB' is rendered obsolete by 'LT_INIT'

Comment: This is merely a warning which can be safely ignored. You may want to try if you have more luck with the cmake build. Just run `cmake .` and afterwards `make`.

Comment: when i try do make, ../../../src/utils/distribution/Distribution_Parameterized.h:34:10: fatal error: 
      'random' file not found

Comment: ooooo finaly I installed sumo and it seems correctly :D I reinstalled xqwartz and then it worked :))))

Answer (score 0):

This worked as of July 2018:

```
brew tap brewsci/science
brew install sumo
```

I also had to follow the advice in [this issue comment](https://github.com/OSGeo/homebrew-osgeo4mac/issues/174#issuecomment-371333912) to resolve an issue with `libproj` ("dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/proj/lib/libproj.12.dylib"). It is not recommended but is extremely effective!

```
cd /usr/local/opt/proj/lib/
ln -s libproj.13.dylib libproj.12.dylib
```